# What is the grammatical name of this: "that he would agree run the state"

Tags: expressions

What is the grammatical name of this:

> He averred "....that he would agree to run the state....'

Comment: If you mean "that he would ...", that is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: I mean ...that he would agree to run the state

Comment: Uh, "..." means "the stuff that follows".

Comment: It's called a _That_-clause, and it's also called a tensed complement clause. Complement clauses act like nouns in a sentence; in the example sentence it's the direct object of _averred_. This particular _that_-clause has its own complement clause, an infinitive this time, _to run the state_, which is the direct object of _would agree_. As you can see, there's a lot of "this" and quite a few grammatical names for it, and pieces of it. The question is not exactly clear.